# копирование конкретных полей из одной таблицы в другую

Tags: mysql

В базе данных *test* мне нужно скопировать из таблицы 'стоимость работ' значение поля 'Стоимость работ' в таблицу 'заказы' в 'Стоимость'. Пишу:

```
INSERT INTO заказы(Стоимость)
SELECT Стоимость работ
FROM стоимость работ
```

Ответ такой:

> 1146 - Table 'test.стоимость' doesn't exist

Как правильно сделать?

Comment: Все русские и особенно содержащие пробелы имена таблиц и столбцов надо заключать в обратные апострофы (которые с буквой Ё на клавиатуре).

Comment: INSERT INTO \`заказы\` (\`Стоимость\`) SELECT \`Стоимость работ\` FROM \`стоимость работ\`

Comment: @Mike, не заметил ваш коммент :)

Answer (score 2):

*Ответ из комментариев*

Все русские и особенно содержащие пробелы имена таблиц и столбцов надо заключать в обратные апострофы (которые с буквой Ё на клавиатуре).

```
INSERT INTO `заказы` (`Стоимость`)
SELECT `Стоимость работ` FROM `стоимость работ`
```